# repairing a damaged grub with centos

Tags: centos, grub, rescue

I have a damaged grub in my centos system. 
to repairing this problem, I use rescue mode and then I execute this follwing comand :

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage

grub-install /dev/mapper/ddf1OSp3

and then reboot ;
```

when boot from hard disk, it's sshow error message "file not found"

when I execute the same comand in grub.conf under grub CMD, it s work fine and the file existe !!

how to proceed to resolve this problem

information about system : 
linux kernel 2.6.

repartition of disk:

```
$ df

/dev/mapper/ddf1OSp3    /

/dev/mapper/ddf1OSp1    /boot

/dev/sdd1               /data

tmpfs                   /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to reinstall `grub` on the LVM. You need to install it on the volume (hard disk, RAID array...) that the motherboard firmware sees. Most commonly:

```
# grub-install /dev/sda
```

In some cases, something else other than `/dev/sda` will make more sense.

Comment: according to df command, the root of my system is located in this repartition "/dev/mapper/ddf1OSp3".

Comment: @EllouzeAnis: That doesn't matter.  Grub is executed directly by the motherboard firmware (BIOS or EFI), which doesn't understand LVM. (`/dev/mapper/*` indicates that you're using LVM.) By putting Grub on the LVM, you've simply hidden it from the mobo FW. Besides, you don't install Grub on the root *filesystem* anyway. You generally install it on the first physical volume. The mobo FW runs Grub from there, and *Grub* then goes and finds your OS and boots that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this tutorial can help you?

## Dual Boot Installation with Grub

Installation of Grub2 and dual boot with windows 10

If your Grub configuration is not as you like follow this tutorial.
First reinstall Grub.

```
sudo yum reinstall grub2-tools
```

Login as root in a terminal

```
su
```

In another terminal , get information about your Windows 10 hard drive, in my case it was named '/dev/sdb1'

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In my configuration, my windows 10 disk was on another hard drive. **Follow only if you are in the same situation.**

In the root terminal, navigate to the grub configuration directory

```
 cd  /etc/grub.d/
```

Now we must find the UUID of your Windows 10 hard drive, enter this command in your non-root terminal

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Find the UUID code next to your disk something like: 40S863A9D8619F12

Now in the root terminal enter the command:

```
nano 40_custom
```

Inside this file enter your windows 10 configuration using GRUB standard. Use the UUID code previously found inside the configuration. In my case my config is:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
        insmod ntfs
        insmod ntldr
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod search_fs_uuid
        search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 40S863A9D8619F12
        ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

Save and exit nano. Now we need to generate a new GRUB configuration file. Enter the command:

```
grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Voilà !!!! Try the configuration with a fresh restart

Source:
http://dareneiri.github.io/Configuring-Grub-2-on-CentOS-7/
https://ihaveabackup.net/article/grub2-entry-for-windows-10-uefi

### (Optional) Install GRUB customizer

If you want to have a sexy GRUB menu you can install grub-customizer using this tutorial:
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/grub-customizer-5.0.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html